# Python: SocketServer closes TCP connection unexpectedly

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, network-programming, twisted

I would like to implement a TCP/IP network client application that sends requests to a Python [SocketServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html) and expects responses in return. I have started out with the official Python [SocketServer sample code](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html#socketserver-tcpserver-example):

`server.py:`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import SocketServer

class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        request  = self.rfile.readline().strip()
        print "RX [%s]: %s" % (self.client_address[0], request)

        response = self.processRequest(request)

        print "TX [%s]: %s" % (self.client_address[0], response)
        self.wfile.write(response)

    def processRequest(self, message):
        if   message == 'request type 01':
            return 'response type 01'
        elif message == 'request type 02':
            return 'response type 02'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer(('localhost', 12345), MyTCPHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

`client.py:`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    sock.connect(('127.0.0.1', 12345))

    data = 'request type 01'
    sent = sock.sendall(data + '\n')
    if sent == 0:
        raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")

    received = sock.recv(1024)
    print "Sent:     {}".format(data)
    print "Received: {}".format(received)

    data = 'request type 02'
    sent = sock.sendall(data + '\n')
    if sent == 0:
        raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")

    received = sock.recv(1024)
    print "Sent:     {}".format(data)
    print "Received: {}".format(received)

except Exception as e:
    print e

finally:
    sock.close()
```

`server.py` output:

```
RX [127.0.0.1]: request type 01
TX [127.0.0.1]: response type 01
```

`client.py` output:

```
Sent:     request type 01
Received: response type 01
[Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

What am doing wrong ? It seems the server is closing the connection. How can I make it stay open ?

Note: This is a follow-up question to [C++/Qt: QTcpSocket won't write after reading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29549878)

**Update (after [abarnert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29572128)):**

What I take away from this is that `SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler` is not the most recent design and while it allows me to connect over a network, it doesn't really support me with all the TCP/IP-related aspects I need to take care of to implement robust communication.

This has been addressed in Python 3 with [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio.html), but as the project lives in Python 2, that's not an option. I have therefore implemented the server and client described above in [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/):

`server.py:`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver
from twisted.internet import reactor

class SimpleProtocol(LineReceiver):

    def connectionMade(self):
        print 'connectionMade'

    # NOTE: lineReceived(...) doesn't seem to get called

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print 'dataReceived'
        print 'RX: %s' % data

        if   data == 'request type 01':
            response = 'response type 01'
        elif data == 'request type 02':
            response = 'response type 02'
        else:
            response = 'unsupported request'

        print 'TX: %s' % response
        self.sendLine(response)

class SimpleProtocolFactory(Factory):

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return SimpleProtocol()

reactor.listenTCP(12345, SimpleProtocolFactory(), interface='127.0.0.1')
reactor.run()
```

`client.py:`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol
from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint, connectProtocol

class SimpleClientProtocol(Protocol):
    def sendMessage(self, msg):
        print "[TX]: %s" % msg
        self.transport.write(msg)

def gotProtocol(p):
    p.sendMessage('request type 01')
    reactor.callLater(1, p.sendMessage, 'request type 02')
    reactor.callLater(2, p.transport.loseConnection)

point = TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, '127.0.0.1', 12345)
d = connectProtocol(point, SimpleClientProtocol())
d.addCallback(gotProtocol)
reactor.run()
```

The client doesn't close, but idles until <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Twisted might take a while to get my head around, but for the job at hand, it clearly seems more reasonable to employ a tested and tried framework than to do all this groundwork myself.

**NOTE:** This is continued at [Twisted XmlStream: How to connect to events?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29683769)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that in a `TCPHandler`, a "request" is actually a complete connection, from beginning to end.* Your handler gets called on `accept`, and when you return from it, the socket gets closed.

If you want to build a request-response-protocol handler on top of that, which processes multiple protocol-level requests on a single socket-level request, you have to do that yourself (or use a higher-level framework). (Subclasses like [`BaseHTTPServer`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/basehttpserver.html) demonstrate how to do this.)

For example, you can just use a loop within your `handle` function. Of course you probably want to add an exception handler here and/or deal with EOF from `rfile` (note `self.rfile.readline()` will return `''` for EOF, but `'\n'` for a blank line, so you have to check it before calling `strip` unless you want a blank line to mean "quit" in your protocol). For example:

```
def handle(self):
    try:
        while True:
            request  = self.rfile.readline()
            if not request:
                break
            request = request.rstrip()
            print "RX [%s]: %s" % (self.client_address[0], request)

            response = self.processRequest(request)

            print "TX [%s]: %s" % (self.client_address[0], response)
            self.wfile.write(response + '\n')
    except Exception as e:
        print "ER [%s]: %r" % (self.client_address[0], e)
    print "DC [%s]: disconnected" % (self.client_address[0])
```

---

This will *often* work with your existing client, at least over localhost on an unloaded machine, but it's not actually correct, and "often works" is rarely good enough. See [TCP sockets are byte streams, not message streams](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/sockets-are-byte-streams-not-message.html) for a longer discussion, but briefly, you *also* need to do the stuff mentioned in [David Schwarz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29571816/908494): append newlines to what you write from the server (which I already did above), and have the client read line by line instead of just trying to read 1024 bytes at a time (which you can do by writing your own buffer-and-split-lines code, or just by using the [`makefile`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/socket.html#socket.socket.makefile) method, so it can use `rfile.readline()` just like the server side does.)

Not fixing the client won't cause the problems that answer claims, but it *will* cause problems like this:

```
Sent:     request type 01
Received: resp
Sent:     request type 02
Received: onse type 01
response typ
```

And you can see that in a real program that actually tried to process the responses programmatically, a response like `resp` or `onse type 01\nresponse typ` isn't going to be very useful…

---

<sub>* Note that `SocketServer` is an ancient design that nobody really loves. There's a reason Python 3 added [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio.html), and that people in Python 2 usually use third-party frameworks like [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/) and [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/). They're both simpler for simple tasks, and more flexible/powerful (and a lot more efficient) for complex tasks.</sub>

Answer (score -3):

The client is broken. It calls `recv` just once and then closes the connection without ensuring it has received everything the server had to send.

The correct way to fix this depends on the protocol you are using, which you haven't explained. It's not apparent from the server code what the protocol for server to client "messages" is. What is the client supposed to expect to get from the server? The server, for example, expects a *line* from the client, a message marked with a newline to indicate the end of the line. So the server knows when it has received a message by checking for a  newline. How is the client supposed to do it? Where is that code?

I'll assume for the sake of argument that your protocol always uses messages and defines a message as terminated by a newline.

```
    request  = self.rfile.readline().strip()
```

This reads a *message* because it calls `readline`.

```
sent = sock.sendall(data + '\n')
```

This sends a *message* because it sends a series of bytes terminated by a newline.

```
received = sock.recv(1024)
```

Oops, this just receives some bytes, not a message. There needs to be code to check if a newline was received and, if not, call `recv` again, otherwise, calling `close` will force an abnormal close of the socket (because the message was not, and can never be, received), which is precisely what you are seeing.

Comment: The advice here is generally good, but the basic point is wrong—the client calls `recv`, then `sendall`, then `recv` again, so the problem is _not_ that it calls `recv` just once and then closes the connection. The problem is that the second `recv` fails with an `ECONNRESET`.

Comment: If the client calls `close` without reading the full message, then the next `recv` in the server will fail with `ECONNRESET`. There may be other problems, but closing the connection after a single `recv` will definitely cause the connection to reset and the next `recv` on the other side will detect this.

Comment: But that's the point: the client _doesn't_ call `close`. The next thing after `sendall` is another `recv`; no possible `close` in between. The problem is that the _server_ is closing the socket, not the client.

Comment: There's a `close` right after the second `recv` (in the `finally` block). If that `recv` doesn't receive the whole message, the connection will terminate abnormally.

Comment: But the error comes from the second `recv`. (You can tell that, because if the `recv` already happened, it would have to print the second set of `TX` and `RX` lines, or print the exception, before getting to the `close`. In this case, it prints the exception, as you can see from the OP's output.) Also, closing a socket with leftover data in the buffer doesn't cause an abnormal termination; it's a perfectly legal thing to do (as you can tell from the fact that the OP's output doesn't have an exception with traceback).

Comment: Another way to see this is to just try running it yourself, either in the debugger, or with the `print e` replaced by something that prints the whole traceback so you can see that it came from the second `sock.recv(1024)` (most simply, just remove the `except` entirely…). Or just run his existing client against the modified server in my answer and see that it works.

Comment: As I said, there may be other problems. Running it myself won't help because the other problems may trigger before this one. Closing a socket with unreceived data in the buffer will cause an abnormal close of the socket. [Consider two peers, A and B, communicating via TCP. If B closes a socket and there is any data in B’s receive
queue, B sends a TCP RST to A instead of following the standard TCP closing protocol, resulting in an error return
value from recv( ).](http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/practical/JavaSockets/RecvQClose.pdf).

Comment: Whatever other bugs he has, he definitely has this one, and it can cause the connection to close abnormally.

Comment: Again, run it yourself, and you will see that with his server, you get an error from the second `recv` and no error from the `close`, just as his output shows, and that with my modified server, you get success from the second `recv` and again no error from the `close`.  If you fiddle with things so either `recv` gets less than a full response, then of course you'll end up with nonsense like `Received: response t` followed by `Received: ype  01response type 02`, but you still won't get an error.

Comment: Also, the link you gave doesn't show what you think it does. If the client closes the socket without receiving the last packet, then yes, the _server_ may get an error on its next `recv`. But it can't possibly cause the _client_ to get an error from `close`, which is what you're claiming will happen. (If you want to solve the server problem, you have to do it on the server side—as I did in my answer, but putting a `try` around the whole server loop, which you _already_ need anyway to handle things like the network going down.)

Comment: Dude, what are you talking about ? The code I've posted calls `recv()` twice. It also clearly shows what messages are exchanged - and it appends `\n` to indicate the protocol is line-based. Also, all messages are shorter than the 1024 max bytes, so all messages should easily fit in there.

Comment: @abarnert As I've said over and over, he may have other problems. But he does have the problem that I described, and it can cause the connection to close abnormally. That the client gets an error doesn't show he doesn't have a problem that would cause the server to get an error. - To ssc: There is no "in there" for messages to fit. TCP is a byte-stream protocol and if you send more than one byte, the receiver may receive them in any combination.

Comment: @ssc: "All messages are shorter than 1024 max bytes" doesn't matter with TCP. A 20-byte `send` could still show up split over two (or 20) `recv` calls, or merged together with another `send` into the same `recv`. TCP only gives you a stream of bytes, not a stream of messages. (You're right about everything else, however.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Sure, yes, his code does have another problem besides the one he's asking about. That doesn't mean that solving that other problem will solve the problem he's asking about. In fact, it cannot possibly solve the problem he's asking about. Which means this is not an answer to his question.

Comment: @abarnert His question is, "What am doing wrong ?". This is something he is doing wrong. And it's much more serious than the other problem because the other problem is just slightly incorrect code whereas this is a fundamental misunderstanding about how to use TCP. (Did you read his comment above? He thinks TCP can glue application bytes together, and this is reflected in both his code and his design. It's the most serious thing he's doing wrong, and you are doing him a disservice by pointing him away from it, downvoting it, encouraging others to downvote, and so on.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: His question is, "What am I doing wrong ? It seems the server is closing the connection. How can I make it stay open ?" The answer is that the server _is_ closing the connection, because that's what he's telling it to do; how he can make it stay open is to not tell it to close. Nothing in this answer even hints at the solution. Meanwhile, I didn't do anything to point him away from the other problem–I covered the same thing in my answer, and also responded to his comment. But telling him that this will solve the problem he's asking about when it won't is not going to help him.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Also, I didn't downvote your answer, although I did think about it. It's definitely not useless, there's no wrong facts in it, and I'm torn on whether to consider it misleading or not, so I left it unvoted. Presumably at least 3 people believe it _is_ misleading, but none of them have commented here to explain why, so that's just a guess.

Comment: @abarnert Likely because you argued convincingly, though incorrectly, that "the basic point is wrong" and that "the problem is not that it calls recv just once and then closes the connection".

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Well, the reason my argument is convincing is that it's correct, so don't blame me for that…